# Integrating a function of a random variable

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

I have $$\int_{1}^{4}(2x+2)(\frac{1}{2})dx$$ where $x$ is a random variable distributed uniformly on $[0,2]$. Is this ‘impermissible’, given that $4$ is not in the support of $x$? For example, I know that I am not allowed to do: $$\int_{1}^{4}(\frac{1}{2})dx$$ as I will get a value (probability) greater than $1$. Is the first integral ‘disallowed’ on similiar grounds?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF of $X$ is $$f(x)= \begin{cases} \frac 12, & x\in[0,2] \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ I assume you are supposed to calculate the expected value of $2x+2$. This will be $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (2x+2)f(x) dx $$ Since $f$ is zero everywhere except in $[0,2]$, this becomes $$\int_0^2 (2x+2)\frac 12 dx $$ So in a way, your integral does not give you the expected value, but ignoring everything else, it’s still just another integral about which nothing is impermissible.

Comment: Thank you. I want to find the expected value of $2x+2$ over $[1,4]$.

Comment: More generally, if I want to find the expected value of $2x+2$ over $[a,b], a<b$, should I write $\int_{\max\{0, a\}}^{\max\{2, b\}}(2x+2)dx?$

Comment: @Charles That doesn’t work for example for $a,b\gt 2$. You could write $$\int_{[a,b] \cap [0,2]} (2x+2)\frac 12 dx$$

Comment: Apologies, why would that work? For instance, if $a=3, b=4$, the union you have defined is an empty set.

Comment: It’s an intersection, and yes, in that case the integral should be $0$, as the pdf is zero in $[3,4]$.

Comment: Right, understood. Thank you very much.